# Invisible app on Facebook pages profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Is there any way to have an app on a 'pages' profile on Facebook that doesn't show a tab on the public profile.

I have tried adding the app (with a pages tab) and hiding the tab after adding it to the page however this seems to cause it to be automatically removed completely.

Comment: What would be the motivation for such a thing?

Comment: It's for a statistics tracking app for a client who does not wish for there to be an extra random tab on their page

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you can not do this. Your app is not called every time a user enters a page even if your app is added to the page, only when the user clicks the app in the page, facebook loads your app in an iframe (inside the page profile) and only then can you "track statistics", your app won't be able to do its' tracking otherwise.

Comment: It's doesn't track its own statistics, it's to allow access to the insights api from the app. The stats works fine but the client doesn't want the tab visible on the page and facebook seems to automatically remove the app once the tab is hidden.

Comment: Oh. Now I understand what you're after, sorry for being a bit slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible by enabling "Sandbox" mode for application. Once sandboxed application (as well as Page tab) will be visible only to Administrators/Developers/Test users of application.

So generally you may enable sandbox mode and add users as Test Users for an application.